# How can I create and select a servlet in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlets

How can I create and select a servlet in IntelliJ IDEA? I'm creating a Jakarta EE project, clicking on Java, and creating a new file, but I can't find the option to create a servlet.

I can create it manually, but that takes quite a while.

Comment: A servlet is nothing more then a java class that extends `HttpServlet`.